# FIFO - reading from top level process, writing from bottom level process

Tags: c, ipc, named-pipes, fifo

I'm trying to communicate between the top and bottom level processes of my program. First I create the FIFO, then I have a for loop to fork n processes. Inside the for loop, I check if a process is a bottom level process and if it is, I write to the FIFO.

I'm confused on how I can read from the FIFO after the bottom level process writes to it. If I try to read before the loop, the loop never executes because nothing was written. If I try to read during the loop, in the parent section of the code, other parents can read it as well. If I try to read after the for loop, the code loop never finishes because it gets stuck when the last child tries to write. Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>

#define MAX_BUF 1024

int main(int argc, char **argv){

    int numprocs = atoi(argv[1]);
    int lev = numprocs;
    fprintf(stdout,"ALIVE: Level %d process with pid=%d, child of ppid=%d.\n", lev, getpid(), getppid());
    int currpid = getpid();

    //create shared memory
    const int SIZE = numprocs * sizeof(int);
    const char *name = "dleggio1OS";
    int shm_fd;
    int *ptr;
    shm_fd = shm_open(name, O_CREAT | O_RDWR, 0666);
    ftruncate(shm_fd, SIZE);
    ptr = mmap(0, SIZE, PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, shm_fd, 0);
    *ptr = getpid();

    //create fifo
    int fd;
    char *myfifo = "/tmp/dleggio1fifo";
    mkfifo(myfifo, 0666);
    //read fifo
    /*char buff[MAX_BUF];
    fd = open(myfifo,O_RDONLY);
    read(fd,buff,MAX_BUF);
    printf("process %d received %s message.\n",getpid(),buff);
    close(fd);*/


    //spawn procs
    int i;
    for(i = 1; i < numprocs; i++){
        lev--;
        int pfds[2];
        char buf[30];
        if(pipe(pfds) == -1){
            perror("pipe");
            exit(1);
        }
        pid_t pid;


        if((pid = fork()) < 0){
            perror("fork");
            exit(1);
        }

        if(pid == 0){ //child

            ptr[i] = getpid();

            close(pfds[1]);
            if(read(pfds[0], buf, 3) <= 0){
                perror("child");
                exit(1);
            }
            int check = atoi(buf);
            fprintf(stdout,"ALIVE: Level %d process with pid=%d, child of ppid=%d.\n", check, ptr[i], ptr[i-1]);

            if(check == 1){ //leaf
                //write to fifo
                fd = open(myfifo, O_WRONLY);
                write(fd,"leaf",sizeof("leaf"));
                close(fd);
                return 0;
            }

        }
        else{ //parent
            close(pfds[0]);
            char hold[3];
            sprintf(hold,"%d",lev);
            if(write(pfds[1], hold, 3) <= 0){
                perror("parent");
                exit(1);
            }
            //read fifo
            /*char buff[MAX_BUF];
            fd = open(myfifo,O_RDONLY);
            read(fd,buff,MAX_BUF);
            printf("process %d received %s message.\n",getpid(),buff);
            close(fd);*/

            wait(NULL);
            return 0;
        }
    }

    //read fifo

    /*char buff[MAX_BUF];
    fd = open(myfifo,O_RDONLY);
    read(fd,buff,MAX_BUF);
    printf("received %s message.\n",buff);
    close(fd);*/

    shm_unlink(name);
    unlink(myfifo);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> If I try to read during the loop, in the parent section of the code,
>   other parents can read it as well.

They can all read from the FIFO because you are creating the FIFO before forking any processes; thus, they're all using the same one.  If you want each parent/child pair to have a private FIFO that only they can use, then you'll need to move your `mkfifo()` call inside the loop and create a FIFO (with a unique name) for each `fork()`.

Comment: how can I get only the top level parent and bottom level child to have a private FIFO?

Comment: In each loop iteration, create a new FIFO with a unique name (e.g. add the loop counter to the end of the name) and have the parent/child use that.  Each iteration will then only know the name for it's private FIFO and won't be able to access anyone else's.